# CouchDB boas práticas para atualização de documentos relacionados

Tags: javascript, node.js, nosql, couchdb

Estou utilizando `CouchDB` e `NodeJs` com esses exemplos de documentos.

```
Role {
  _id,
  name
}

User {
  _id,
  email,
  password,
  role: {
    _id,
    name
  }
}
```

Qual a melhor prática para quando eu atualizar uma `Role`, também atualiza-la dentro de `User` caso o `_id` das `Roles` forem iguais.

Este é só um exemplo, na aplicação terão casos de documentos duplicados em diversas partes do banco, necessitando desse tipo de atualização para evitar inconsistências.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O couchdb é um pouco diferente das bases dados relacionais, por isso a forma como construimos as aplicações também muda um pouco. Respondendo ao seu caso, o que eu faço é criar um modelo "roles" no backend node e outro "user". Depois sempre que for criado um novo user ele será gravado na bd couch como documento json e terá um objeto role. Se esse user for mais tarde atualizado, no couchdb, isso será um novo documento com uma _rev nova, isto é, para gravar esse update, terás de passar o documento completo, e nessa altura caso os roles também tenham sido alterados, irão ficar atualizados.
Se precisares de manter compatibilidades com roles anteriores, podes incluir um parâmetro "versão" no objeto role.

**Exemplo:**

```
{
_id: "someUser",
"doc_type": "user",
"name": "his name",
"role": {
  "Version": 1,
  "description": "admin"
}
}
```